# Texturing a box in OpenGL 4.5 - (doen't work)

Tags: c++, opengl

I have drawn a box. I added the basic class that deals vao and vbo.

```
class BasicObject_V2
{
public:
    BasicObject_V2(GLuint typeOfPrimitives = 0){
        this->typeOfPrimitives = typeOfPrimitives;
        switch (this->typeOfPrimitives){
            case GL_QUADS: numVertsPerPrimitive = 4; break;
}}
void allocateMemory(){
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertexAttributes), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 48, (const void*)0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 48, (const void*)12);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 48, (const void*)24);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 48, (const void*)40);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    }

    GLuint vboID;
    GLuint vaoID;
    GLuint typeOfPrimitives;
    GLuint numVertsPerPrimitive;

    int getNumberOfVertices(){
        return vertices.size();
    }

    struct vertexAttributes{
        glm::vec3 pos;
        glm::vec3 normal;
        glm::vec4 color;
        glm::vec2 texCoord;
    };

    std::vector<vertexAttributes> vertices;
};
```

Here is the my Box-class.

```
class Box_V2 : public BasicObject_V2 {
public:

    Box_V2(float width = 1, float height = 1, float length = 1) : BasicObject_V2(GL_QUADS) {
        float wHalf = width / 2.0f;
        float hHalf = height / 2.0f;
        float lHalf = length / 2.0f;
        vertexAttributes va;
        glm::vec3 corners[8];
        corners[0] = glm::vec3(-wHalf, -hHalf, lHalf);
        corners[1] = (...)
        glm::vec3 normals[6];
        normals[0] = glm::vec3(0, 0, 1); // front
        //(...)

        // FRONT
        va.pos = corners[0];
        va.normal = normals[0];
        va.texCoord = glm::vec2(0.0, 0.0);
        vertices.push_back(va);
        //...
        allocateMemory();
    }
};
```

Also I have set the texture for it (acoording to the opengl superbible example), but it does work at all.

```
static GLubyte checkImage[128][128][4];
void makeCheckImage(void)
{
    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 0; i<128; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<128; j++) {
            c = ((((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)) == 0)) * 255;
            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte)c;
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte)c;
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte)c;
            checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte)255;     
        }}}

void init(){
    glClearColor(0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 1);

    //Create a Texture
    makeCheckImage();

    //Texure 
    glGenTextures(4, tex);
    //glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, tex);//4.5
    glTextureStorage2D(tex[0], 0, GL_RGBA32F, 2, 2);    
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, checkImage);
    //glTextureSubImage2D(tex[0], 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, checkImage);//4.5

    //load the shader
    programID = loadShaders("vertex.vsh", "fragment.fsh");
    glUseProgram(programID);

    //create a box 
    box_v2 = new Box_V2();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);   
}}

    void drawing(BasicObject* object){
       glBindVertexArray(object->vaoID);
       glDrawArrays(object->typeOfPrimitives, 0, object->getNumberOfVertices() * object->numVertsPerPrimitive);
       glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

This is my shaders:
VS:

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 rotate;(...)

out vec4 v_normal;
out vec4 v_color;
out vec4 v_pos;
out vec2 v_texCoord;

void main(){
    v_normal = rotate*vec4(normal,1);//*model;
    v_color=color;
    v_texCoord=texCoord;
    gl_Position = rotate*scale*trans*vec4(pos.xyz, 1);
}
```

And FS:

```
#version 450 core
in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
out vec4 outColor;

void main(){ 
  //outColor=texelFetch(ourTexture, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0); //4.5  
  outColor=texture(ourTexture,v_texCoord*vec2(3.0, 1.0));
}
```

Now it draws a black box without any texture on it. I'm new  in OpenGL and I can't find where is the problem.

Comment: You should use [`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) before `glBindTexture`, and assign `0` to the `ourTexture` uniform. I'm unsure whether the defaults do that already, so that's not an answer. Scattering `glGetError()`'s around may reveal the problem too.

Comment: Shoudn't the type parameter in `glTexImage2D` be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` since you have a `GLubyte checkImage[128][128][4]`? And since you prepare an alpha channel, the internal format should most probably be `GL_RGBA`?

Comment: @Quentin: `GL_TEXTURE0` is the default texture unit set.

Comment: glGetError() -shows nothing at all. In glTexImage2D I tried GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , but still no changes. puzzled...

Comment: @BDL: `GL_TEXTURE0` may be the default texture unit binding, but it is *not* the default uniform value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code. It looks like you tried to write it one way, then tried to write it another way, leading to some kind of Frankenstein's code where it's not really one way or the other.

```
glGenTextures(4, tex);
//glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, tex);//4.5
glTextureStorage2D(tex[0], 0, GL_RGBA32F, 2, 2);
```

This is a perfect example. You use the non-DSA `glGenTextures` call, but you immediately turn around and use the [DSA](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Direct_State_Access) `glTextureStorage2D` call on it. You *cannot* do that. Why? Because `tex[0]` hasn't been created yet.

`glGenTextures` only allocates the *name* for the texture, not its state data. Only by binding the texture does it get contents. That's why DSA introduced the `glCreate*` functions; they allocate both the name and state for the object. This is also why `glCreateTextures` takes a target; that target is part of the texture object's state.

In short, the commented out call was correct all along. Looking at your code as written, the `glTextureStorage2D` call *fails* with an OpenGL error (FYI: turn on KHR_debug to see when errors happen).

So let's look at what your code would look like if we take out the failure parts:

```
glGenTextures(4, tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, checkImage);
```

There are two problems here. First, as BDL mentioned, your data is described incorrectly. You're passing `GLubyte`s, but you told OpenGL you were passing `GLfloat`s. Don't lie to OpenGL.

Second, there's the [internal format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). Because you used an unsized internal format (and because you're not in OpenGL ES land), the format your implementation chooses will be *unsigned normalized*. It won't be a 32-bit floating point format. If you want one of those, you must *explicitly* ask for it, with `GL_RGBA32F`.

Furthermore, because you allocated mutable storage for your texture (ie: because `glTextureStorage2D` failed), you now have a problem. You only allocated one mipmap level, but the default filtering mode will try to fetch from multiple mipmaps. And you never set the texture's [mipmap range](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Mipmap_range) to only sample from the first. So your texture is not complete. An immutable storage texture would have made the mipmap range match what you allocated, but mutable storage textures aren't so nice.

You should *always* set your mipmap range when creating mutable storage textures:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0); //It's a closed range.
```

Lastly, you bind the texture to unit 0 for rendering (mostly by accident, since you never call `glActiveTexture`). But you never bother to inform your shader of this, by setting the `ourTexture` uniform value to 0.

Comment: Removed my answer. This is a much better one :)  I hadn't even noticed the `glTextureStorage2D` vs `glTexStorage2D`.

Comment: TNX for such a detailed answer. It helped me to understand the tutorial better. And now my Programm works :))

Comment: Is than possible to only keep the original texture and smallest mipmap?

Answer (score 0):

There are several Problems with your code:

**Data type doesn't match data**

The data comes in an unsigned byte format (`GLubyte checkImage[128][128][4]`) with a size of of 4 bytes per pixel (1 byte per channel), but you tell OpenGL that it is in `GL_FLOAT` format, which would require 16 bytes per pixel (4 bytes per channel).

**Data storage**

See answer from 246Nt.

**Mipmaps/Filters**

Per default OpenGL has the minification filter set to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` which requries the user to supply valid mipmaps for the texture. One can either change this filter to `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST` which do not require mipmaps (see [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml)), or generate mipmaps ([`glGenerateMipmaps`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)).